# Why is my gradle build failing? (could not find method apt())

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

Everything works perfectly fine until I try to use the apt or other plugins with gradle for my annotation processor that I'm writing. I've been able to build and run everything manually (with/without gradle), but having problems as soon as I introduce plugins.  Here's my script:

Here is my buildscript:

```
buildscript {

    evaluationDependsOn('compiler')
    evaluationDependsOn('core')

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        flatDir { dirs './make' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.9"
        classpath ':core:0.1'
        apt ':compiler:0.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.9"
}

group 'bundle'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

I'm using the [gradle-apt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin).  I've also tried using [Palantir's annotation processing plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-processors) and the exact error is thrown, leading me to believe that it is nothing wrong with the plugins and something with my configuration and/or versions.

local gradle version: 2.1
and
Gradle wrapper: 3.4.1

Annotation processing is enabled in Intellij.  I've also checked that I use the correct URL for the remote plugin repositories.  I've tried rolling back the gradlew version.

Intellij warns me that "Unindexed remote maven repositories found" but according to the idea forums [it's a bug but won't affect a build.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693)  Other than that, I have no idea what's making this fail.

Here's the output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/$USER/IdeaProjects/$PROJECT/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Dynamic-MVP'.
> Could not find method apt() for arguments [:compiler:0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add it to the buildscript dependencies, that is not correct. Buildscript dependencies can be only `classpath`. You rather need to add it to your project dependencies as:

```
dependencies {
    apt ':compiler:0.1'
}
```

Out of the `buildscript` closure.

Comment: Thank you! I read through all of the gradle user guides yet I guess that distinction between buildscript and project wasn't very clear.